# Trying to get Thumbnail to work on Sharepoint O365

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, metadata, thumbnail

I am trying to get Thumbnail to display in a table view. But am getting the Broken image symbol. See image below.

[image]

Comment: What type of library you are using?

Comment: I currently Using Document library.

Comment: check the URL of the thumbnail and see if it is a valid URL.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Picture library to store images and it has the functionality to load thumbnails.

Adding a Picture Content type to a document library don't create the thumbnails as expected. On the other hand in case of Picture Library it creates new thumbnail for each picture uploaded into a hidden folder `_t`.

Details on enabling the same in a document library require extra effort as described in the article https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/syedi/2010/03/05/need-a-thumbnail-field-in-the-document-library-for-the-uploaded-picture-then-read-this-post/

Comment: I know this is an old post, but see here:  https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/256090/picture-library-thumbnail-url/256094#256094